# Does composition with itself convex implies function convex?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis

Let $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ be a twice differentiable increasing function and suppose that $g:=f \circ f$ is a convex function. Is it true that $f$ itself is convex?

I am aware that the converse implication is true (namely that if $f$ is increasing and convex then $g$ is convex) but this seems to be more difficult.

Comment: If you just want increasing (in contrast to strictly increasing), then pick a function that vanishes on $[0;1/2]$ and never gets bigger than $1/2$, then $g=0$, which is convex, but of course we can tune $f$ such that it is not convex.